# how can i do unit testing for APIs?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, unit-testing, junit

i`am new to unit testing and i have this task to write unit testing for Post API i have only the end point and api body i read a lot in google but i could not figure out how to start , any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a intent, fill it with data if needed, like the data extracted from the QR code and then call startActivity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", 1); //Your id
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

I put an int in the bundle but it could be anything that implements Serializable.

Comment: Is it possible to create **Intent** using appium?

Answer (score 0):

You can reach direct on required screen  with that pages’s activity (as shown `Splash screen` in below example). You can launch activity with below method.

```
public static void launchActivity(Activity activityName) 
{

        ((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).startActivity(activityName);
}
```

**How you can call this function**

Suppose you have below app package and activity (its for example but you have to use for your app)

```
String appPackage ="my.app.helloworld";

String appActivity = "my.app.helloworld".common.activity.SplashScreen";

launchActivity(new Activity(appPackage, appActivity));
```

You need to set `android:exported="true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to resolve error `java.lang.SecurityException`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.dsquares.lucky/.screens.mainscreens.Wallet.WalletPayment.AddFundsActivity"
    android:label="wallet" 
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: we have **AndroidManifest.xml** file in android app project which contains all set of activity in app and permission for it. Yo have to make  **android:exported="true"** for this activity. You have request your android dev team to do it. updated answer also to show an example